# How to find create a subarray from an array based on pattern match?

Tags: pattern-matching, sub-array

I want to create a subarray from an array based on pattern match.
for example:

```
Object[] o = {"123","134","432","213"}
```

i want to create an array which should contain only those element which starts from 1. i.e

```
 {"123","134"}
```

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the fastest solution i can think.

```
matchArray(regex,array)
    {
    ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
    for(String o in array){
    if(o.match(regex)){
    list.add(o);
    }
    }
    return list.toArray();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution..  How to check for "starts with" in Regex? i mean should i pass "^1*" as value for regex, in above example?

Comment: i believe yes, here is the documentation of regex in java. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html